# pip package gets error at installing aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi

I have made an own pip package and I get this error when I'm installing it.

urllib3 works fine, but aiohttp raises this error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aiohttp (from web-math) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for aiohttp
```

this i my setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

requirements = ["aiohttp", "urllib3"]

classifiers = [
    "Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable",
    "Intended Audience :: Education",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
]

setup(
    name="web_math",
    version="1.0.11",
    description="For online math api",
    long_description=open("README.md").read(),
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    url="https://github.com/mcbabo/webmath",
    author="Moritz",
    license="MIT",
    classifiers=classifiers,
    keywords="discord discord-calc calculator easy-calc simple-calculator discord.py pycord python math",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=requirements,
    include_package_data=True
)
```

Comment: Which version of python do you have installed?. You need Python >= 3.7. Try also update pip

Comment: Python 3.9.7
pip 21.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Which version of python do you have.You need Python >= 3.5 to use aiohttp

Comment: Python 3.9.7 pip 21.1.2

Comment: try using this code in ide terminal or command prompt(activate environment first)

pip install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple

Comment: whats that? pls explain

Comment: It install aiohttp from rasa

Comment: so i have to put this in requirements like this? ["rasa-x --extra-index-url pypi.rasa.com/simple", "urllib3"]

Comment: pip install rasa-x --extra-index-url pypi.rasa.com/simple